# Nifi CaptureChangeMySQL 1.20.0 with PutDatabaseRecord to Oracle

Tags: mysql, oracle, apache-nifi

I am new to Nifi. I want to migrate a MySQL database to Oracle. Am planning to use Nifi for that. For fetching the changes from MySQL, am planning to use CaptureChangeMySQL. How can I Insert/Update/Delete records in Oracle? Can I use PutDatabaseRecord processor? Do I need to have any additional processors to convert data before putDatabaseRecord? will delete work with PutDatabaseRecord?